# Reskinning / makeover an old Access application

Tags: ms-access, skinning

My client has an old Access application written in Access 2003.  It's fairly large and complex, but well established and works well functionally, so redeveloping is not an option.

We'd like to give this a visual makeover to make it look more 'modern'.  No changes in functionality here, simply eye candy.

Can anyone recommend an efficient approach to this?  Are there any reskinning extensions or similar for access?  Would there be any advantage in upgrading to Access 2007?

Comment: Can you give examples of the changes you want? Colors, graphics, fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are themed controls turned on? Themed controls are supported in a2003, and they tend to make 10 year old software only look a few years old.

[image]

The above has themes turned off. Here is the same a2003 with themes turned on:
[image]

And, here is two more:

[image]
[image]

and, now with themes on:

[image]
[image]

So, themes are one way to spruce things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

An app written in A2003 is not old.   Just well seasoned.    One of my current apps that have been added to over the years many times started off in Access 2.0 in 1994 or so.  Others in Access 97.

While Albert, as always, has a good suggestion I couldn't be bothered to add any eye candy.   Database apps are business related apps.   They are not Twitter, MSN Messenger, iPhone or Facebook.    They are meant to be boring and functional.

Now if a client really wanted to pay me by the hour I'd figure it all out and give them the choices and set things up for them.   I'd probably even add the functionality so each user could change as many of the possible options to suit their own tastes.  But I'd let them do the eye candy selections.